# links in email breaking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, sendgrid

I have a rails application and am using devise for authentication. I notice that when the email for resetting the password goes through in production then the link to reset the password breaks and it redirects to my root URL.

In development it takes me to the sign in page and a flash message appears which says that I cannot access this page without a valid token, and must provide the full URL.

while I have customized the look of the email, I am using the devise methods  in order to generate the links, viz. `edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %>`

this should ideally come up in the development environment as
`http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=[GENERATED_TOKEN]`

however it is coming up as follows as observed from the server logs:
`http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_pass=`
`word_token=3DQaz7y_f63yR3MZmReUY5`

on two separate lines. In production I am using sendgrid so I cannot see the url being generated by inspecting the link.

I also notice that every `=` sign gets converted to an `=3D`

Looking forward to some suggestions. Please do let me know if I must provide any more data.

Comment: Did you change your mailer url in production.rb file?

Comment: Yes in `production.rb` the `default_url_options` are set to the url of my application

Comment: The line wrap and the %3d are almost certainly red herrings: that is what quoted printable (one of the encodings used for email) does.

Comment: The most obvious supplemental bit of data would what do those links look like in production?

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes I think that is the problem. The mails are miltipart emails so the links that go through in the textual mail, are fine but the html ones are a mess. The problem is I want to avoid overriding the devise mailer I will have to override each and every delivery method in that case I guess. I am trying to figure out a way to set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header to `7bit`. I tried setting it in the defaults of ApplicationMailer but that did not change anything

Comment: @FrederickCheung in production I use sendgrid so the links point to some sendgrid url which used to resolve properly but now it is not, moreover it redirects back to the root url of the application. Heroku logs show a request to the root url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out the problem, which as it turns out had nothing to do with the transfer encoding. 
At the receiving end the urls do get full resolved properly in spite of the content transfer encoding.

However since I was auto generating the links, they were being generated and sent as `http` links. I am using a CDN that redirects all traffic over `https` a page rule I had added there to resolve a few issues, was causing this `http` link to redirect over `https` and eventually to the application root. This is what was causing the problem.

Generating an absolute url with `https` is what was required.